# Not able to change permission of files/folder shared in samba

Tags: 13.04, networking, permissions, samba

I am trying to change permission and change the group permission of the folders which are shared through SAMBA (Samba PDC). Commands are as follows:

```bsh
# chmod 766 /mnt/Format
```

but nothing changed.

Please help.

Comment: Is this share on local PC or is mounted from network drive?

Comment: share is in local pc different partition (NTFS)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is because you use POSIX-specific command (`chmod`) to change non-POSIX-compliant filesystem (NTFS). The `chown` command also does not work on such filesystems. To change permissions on NTFS shares you should use *`mount` options*.

From `man mount.ntfs`:

```
OPTIONS
       Below is a summary of the options that ntfs-3g accepts.

       uid=value and gid=value
              Set the owner and the group of files and directories. The values
              are  numerical.  The defaults are the uid and gid of the current
              process.
...
       permissions
              Set  standard  permissions  on  created  files  and use standard
              access control.  This option is set by default when a user  map‐
              ping file is present.
```

So, instead of using

```
chmod 766 /mnt/Format
```

use

```
mount -o uid=UID,permissions,remount /mnt/Format
```

See `man mount.ntfs` for further help. There is nice EXAMPLES section which helps understanding how mounting works.